# Angular [ngIf], [ngIfElse] and [ngIfElseIf]

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng-template

I have this code at moment:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someCondition">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="cd.typedType === 'first'" [ngIfElse]="Second">
      <div class="row">
      first
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #Second>
      <div class="row">
      second
      </div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

And it's working.
Is there a way to use an else if? To create something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someCondition">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="cd.typedType === 'first'" [ngIfElseIf]="cd.typedType === 'Second'" [ngIfElse]="cd.typedType === 'Third'>
      <div class="row">
      first
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #Second>
      <div class="row">
      second
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #Third>
      <div class="row">
      third
      </div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

So to move between 3 different template with a basic if/elseif/else?

Comment: have you considered `ngSwitch`? https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngSwitch seems to be the answer you're looking for !

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="someCondition">
    <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="'first'">
      <div class="row">
      first
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="'second'">
      <div class="row">
      second
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="'third'">
      <div class="row">
      third
      </div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Get more infos here :
[angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase)